# How should “四月は君の嘘” be translated?

Tags: translation, word-order

四{し}月{がつ}は君{きみ}の嘘{うそ} is an anime premiered in fall 2014, and I wonder how this anime title should be translated.

The official translation is “Your Lie in April”, but I also came across another form which is “April is Your Lie”. Are these translations are both acceptable? Or is it a one should be preferred to the other?

Here I understood that the place of the subject is important, but the form “April is Your Lie” makes no sense to me. I am aware that, by translating word for word this sentence, one can reach this construction, 
but in this case the meaning does not seem properly transcribed.

Semantically, this is obviously not the month of April which is a lie, it is a metonymy. Thus, in English, the form “April is Your Lie” does not appear convincing (the metonymy is less clear) while on the contrary “Your Lie in April” — the form eventually officially chosen — is closer to the original meaning (and, but that is subjective, also seems more poetic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single phrase can be translated in multiple ways. Doesn't help that Japanese is a very ambiguous language. But "Your Lie In April" seems to be the official translation and fits the story more. After all, it was a lie IN April that started the story, not that April was the lie.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole problem ;-). Your arguments join mine on the meaning. But then, what about the other form, is it at least acceptable?

Comment: @mlpo Given the proper context it could mean "your lie is April", "your lie was in April", "your lie in April", etc.. Whatever the official translation says is probably the best.